# $f$ is strictly decreasing and $g$ is strictly increasing on $R_f$ what we can conclude about $g\circ f$?

Tags: calculus, functions

If function $f$ be strictly decreasing and function $g$ be strictly increasing on $R_f$ which statement is true?

$1) g\circ f\quad \text{is a constant function}$

$2) g\circ f\quad \text{is neither increasing nor decreasing}$

$3) g\circ f\quad \text{is strictly increasing}$

$4) g\circ f\quad \text{is strictly decreasing}$

I think $g\circ f$ is strictly increasing because the input of this function is $R_f$ (range of $f$) and $g$ is strictly increasing on $R_f$ as stated in the questino. But I doubt this answer is correct because I didn't use the first part of the question which says $f$  is strictly decreasing function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Are you sure? Seems to be that $g\circ f$ is strictly decreasing, as $x < y \Rightarrow f(y) < f(x) \Rightarrow g(f(y)) < g(f(x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x>y$, then $f(x)<f(y)$ because $f$ is strictly decreasing. Let’s write $a=f(x)$ and $b=f(y)$. We have $a<b$, so $g(a)<g(b)$ because $g$ is strictly increasing. Hence, if $x>y$, then $(g \circ f)(x)<(g \circ f)(y)$.

$g \circ f$ is strictly decreasing.